# alfresco community 5.0.d - Import categories

Tags: xml, alfresco

Good morning / afternoon,

I am currently testing Alfresco Community 5.0.d and the possibilities it offers.

I would like to know how to import categories from an XML file (or XML files ?). I prefer avoiding using AMP / ACP, as they seem pretty unclear to me.

I've looked into the official documentation : http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-bootstrapping-categories-xml.html ; from what I understood, I need one XML file containing the categories, and another one to "register" the first (I am not sure about what this second one shall consist of). But being quite a newbie, I do not really understand where to put which XML... (or if there are some specific procedures to follow).

I have looked for information about this, but all the topics I found were either related to older versions of Alfresco (and the paths they indicated did not exist in my Alfresco folder) or using relatively "advanced" (at least for me) tools and techniques.

Could someone explain me how to do ?

Thanks in advance, this would help a lot !

Comment: Do you mean on bootstrap or just an ordinary import?

Comment: Documentation lead me to the bootstrap method, but if there is a simpler way ("ordinary import" ?) it is even better !

Comment: I have added custom category xml file as well. Just make sure there are no missing closing tag and you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

**Step 1:**
 Create category file based on format mentioned [here](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-bootstrapping-categories-xml.html)
ex. **custom-category.xml**

```
<view:view xmlns:view="http://www.alfresco.org/view/repository/1.0"
       xmlns:sys="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0"
       xmlns:cm="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0">

<cm:category_root view:childName="cm:categoryRoot">
    <cm:name>categories</cm:name>
    <cm:categories>
     <cm:category view:childName="cm:generalclassifiable">
            <cm:name>General</cm:name>
            <cm:subcategories>
        <cm:category>
        <cm:name>Test1</cm:name>
        <cm:subcategories>
            <cm:category>
                <cm:name>A</cm:name>
                <cm:subcategories>
                    <cm:category>
                        <cm:name>A1</cm:name>
                    </cm:category>
                    <cm:category>
                        <cm:name>A2</cm:name>
                    </cm:category>
                    <cm:category>
                        <cm:name>A3</cm:name>
                    </cm:category>
                    <cm:category>
                        <cm:name>A4</cm:name>
                    </cm:category>
                    <cm:category>
                        <cm:name>A5</cm:name>
                    </cm:category>
                </cm:subcategories>
            </cm:category>

    </cm:categories>
</cm:category_root>
```

**Step 2:**
 Create context file which will be loaded during bootstrap in alfresco and it will load xml file which you have created in first step.  So you entry of above xml will look something like this.

```
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
<bean id="spacesBootstrap-base" parent="spacesStoreImporter" abstract="true" >
    <property name="bootstrapViews">
        <list>              
            <props>
                <prop key="path">/</prop>
                <prop key="location">alfresco/extension/custom-category.xml</prop>
            </props>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Step 3:**
 Place both xml files under following location

**\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension**

and restart your alfresco server.

NOTE: Ideally you should create your module and create these files should be part of those amp files but this is just quick way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer mitpatoliya, I really clears things up.

After several unsuccessful tries, my xml syntax eventually seemed correct enough for the server to restart.

Here are the files I put in C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension :

---

**catego.xml**

```
<view:view xmlns:view="http://www.alfresco.org/view/repository/1.0"
       xmlns:sys="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0"
       xmlns:cm="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0">

        <cm:category>
            <cm:name>Test1</cm:name>
            <cm:subcategories>
                <cm:category>
                    <cm:name>A</cm:name>
                    <cm:subcategories>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>A1</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>A2</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>A3</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>A4</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>A5</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                    </cm:subcategories>
                </cm:category>
                <cm:category>
                    <cm:name>B</cm:name>
                    <cm:subcategories>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>B1</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>B2</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                    </cm:subcategories>
                </cm:category>
                <cm:category>
                    <cm:name>C</cm:name>
                    <cm:subcategories>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>C1</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>C2</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>C3</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                    </cm:subcategories>
                </cm:category>
                <cm:category>
                    <cm:name>D</cm:name>
                    <cm:subcategories>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>D1</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>D2</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>D3</cm:name>
                        </cm:category>
                    </cm:subcategories>
                </cm:category>
            </cm:subcategories>

        </cm:category>

   </view:view>
```

---

**bootstrap-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <bean id="spacesBootstrap-base" parent="spacesStoreImporter" abstract="true">
        <property name="bootstrapViews">
            <list>              
                <props>
                    <prop key="path">/</prop>
                    <prop key="location">alfresco/extension/catego.xml</prop>
                </props>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

However, in the "Category Manager" (Share Admin Tool), I cannot see any of my bootstrapped categories...

I guess one of my xml files went wrong, but I do not understand where...

Any idea ?

Thanks again !

Comment: Is there something in the Alfresco log?

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on a module that uses VDEX as an XML-format to import categories. The VDEX-format is useful for exchanging value lists and maps quite well to Alfresco categories.

It works by importing a url to a vdex file from inside the Category Manager, so it can be imported at runtime.

It also supports importing nested categories

Here's an example file:

```
<vdex:vdex xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:vdex="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsvdex_v1p0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsvdex_v1p0 http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsvdex_v1p0.xsd" orderSignificant="false" profileType="flatTokenTerms">
<vdex:vocabName>
    <vdex:langstring language="x-none">Example categories</vdex:langstring>
    <vdex:langstring language="nl">Example categories</vdex:langstring>
    </vdex:vocabName>
    <vdex:vocabIdentifier>fase-leerproces</vdex:vocabIdentifier>
    <vdex:term orderSignificant="false" validIndex="true">
        <vdex:termIdentifier>cata</vdex:termIdentifier>
        <vdex:caption>
        <vdex:langstring language="nl">Category A</vdex:langstring>
        </vdex:caption>
    </vdex:term>
    <vdex:term orderSignificant="false" validIndex="true">
        <vdex:termIdentifier>catb</vdex:termIdentifier>
        <vdex:caption>
        <vdex:langstring language="nl">Category B</vdex:langstring>
        </vdex:caption>
    </vdex:term>
</vdex:vdex>
```

No release details available yet I'm afraid.