# Alfresco Community 5.0.d - Unable to bootstrap categories

Tags: xml, alfresco

Hi and happy new year to everyone !

This question is a continuation of this one: [Import Categories 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308052/alfresco-community-5-0-d-import-categories)

I am really sorry to bother you once more, but i cannot make my category bootstrap work...

I copied mitpatoliya's "custom-category.xml" script (from the previous question) and added the missing closing tags, but none of my new categories appear after restarting alfresco.

Here are my files :

**catego.xml**

```
<view:view xmlns:view="http://www.alfresco.org/view/repository/1.0"
   xmlns:sys="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0"
   xmlns:cm="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0">

<cm:category_root view:childName="cm:categoryRoot">
    <cm:name>categories</cm:name>
    <cm:categories>
        <cm:category view:childName="cm:generalclassifiable">
            <cm:name>General</cm:name>
            <cm:subcategories>
                <cm:category>
                    <cm:name>Test1</cm:name>
                    <cm:subcategories>
                        <cm:category>
                            <cm:name>A</cm:name>
                            <cm:subcategories>
                                <cm:category>
                                    <cm:name>A1</cm:name>
                                </cm:category>
                                <cm:category>
                                    <cm:name>A2</cm:name>
                                </cm:category>
                                <cm:category>
                                    <cm:name>A3</cm:name>
                                </cm:category>
                                <cm:category>
                                    <cm:name>A4</cm:name>
                                </cm:category>
                                <cm:category>
                                    <cm:name>A5</cm:name>
                                </cm:category>
                            </cm:subcategories>
                        </cm:category>
                    </cm:subcategories>
                </cm:category>
            </cm:subcategories>
        </cm:category>
    </cm:categories>
</cm:category_root>

</view:view>
```

**bootstrap-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <bean id="spacesBootstrap-base" parent="spacesStoreImporter" abstract="true">
        <property name="bootstrapViews">
            <list>              
                <props>
                    <prop key="path">/</prop>
                    <prop key="location">alfresco/extension/catego.xml</prop>
                </props>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Both of my XML files are located in C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension.

There does not seem to be any error in my alfresco.log ; however, there does not seem to be any sign of bootstrap files either...

I also noticed that :

- if I add on purpose syntax errors in boostrap-context.xml, alfresco does not start correctly - and there are errors in the log, like : "Offending resource: class path resource [alfresco/application-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in XML document from file [C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\bootstrap-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 3; The end-tag for element type "property" must end with a '>' delimiter."
- on the other hand, if I add syntax errors in catego.xml, alfresco starts correctly, and there is no such message in the log.

I guessed that maybe my context file does not call my catego.xml correctly... Maybe the "bean" name/parent, the "abstract=true" and/or the "property name" are not correct ? Or maybe a line is missing ?

I have tried to find understandable info about this and experimented several other XML lines found on the Internet, but without success.

So I am stuck. Does someone know what goes wrong ?

Thank you again for your help !!

Comment: Before testing the stuff I suggest in my answer. Check that this is not a solr indexing problem. Look for the categories in the NodeBrowser first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers ! That may seem stupid, but : 

- what exactly should I check from the node browser ? (and how ?) 

- concerning your answer below, do you suggest that I delete the three lines from "<cm:category_root" (and the corresponding closing tags) in my catego.xml, and that I change the "props" part of the bootstrap file (why changing the key="location" ?) ? 

Thanks in advance ! (and sorry for asking so many questions, I have trouble understanding how all of this works).

Comment: Yes, I would have deleted them and instead added the path as in my answer below. However check the NodeBrowser in the admin tools first. Go to ```/cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable``` to find the categories

Comment: Thanks ! I implemented your suggestions in my xml files, but it unfortunately did not work... I checked the NodeBrowser before and after, and all I could see under the path you indicated were the built-in categories... (Languages, Regions, etc.) Any idea why ?

Comment: Check that startup log. Does the bootstrapPatch fire at all?

Comment: There are 4 lines containing the word "Bootstrap" in my log when I start tomcat :
 Line 5: 2016-01-19 16:57:08,986 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
 Line 10: 2016-01-19 16:57:16,708 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Connecting to database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/alfresco, UserName=alfresco, PostgreSQL Native Driver

Comment: Line 11: 2016-01-19 16:57:16,708 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Schema managed by database dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.
 Line 12: 2016-01-19 16:57:18,294 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] No changes were made to the schema.

Answer (score 1):

When I am importing categories I dont use that category_root-tag? Never seen that before. Instead you should put them under the generalclassifiable category by specifying a repository path in the spring-bean definition of the bootstrap patch, like this:

```
    <property name="bootstrapView">
  <props>
    <prop key="encoding">UTF-8</prop>
    <prop key="path">/cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable</prop>
    <prop key="location">alfresco/module/demo-repo/context/bootstrap/catego.xml</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```

EDIT:

To import new categories to an already bootstrapped repository you will need to configure a GenericBootstrapPatch instead, below is an example from a customer where a new category is added, use the same patch and location properties like before:

```
  <bean id="patch.spiritNattbildCategory" class="org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.impl.GenericBootstrapPatch" parent="basePatch">
<property name="id">
  <value>patch.spiritNattbildCategory</value>
</property>
<property name="description">
  <value>patch.spiritNattbildCategory.description</value>
</property>
<property name="fixesFromSchema">
  <value>0</value>
</property>
<property name="fixesToSchema">
  <value>${version.schema}</value>
</property>
<property name="targetSchema">
  <value>10000</value>
</property>
<property name="force" value="true" />

<property name="importerBootstrap">
  <ref bean="spacesBootstrap" />
</property>

<property name="bootstrapView">
  <props>
    <prop key="path">/cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable/cm:Spirit/cm:Listboxar/cm:Bilder/cm:Bildtyp</prop>
    <prop key="location">alfresco/module/smotamp/bootstrap/smot-bildtyp-nattbild.xml</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```